# Play! Framework 2.0 connecting to multiple databases

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to connect to multiple databases in Play 2.0. Here's how my application.conf looks like:

```
db.default.driver= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scg2?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;amp;autoreconnect=true"
db.default.user=root
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

db.scg2_shard1.driver= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.scg2_shard1.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scg2_shard1?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;amp;autoreconnect=true"
db.scg2_shard1.user=root
db.scg2_shard1.jndiName=ShardDS_1
```

And here's how the persistence.xml looks like

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>        
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="shardPersistenceUnit_1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>ShardDS_1</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>        
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The connections are being properly initialized and I can correctly execute SELECT queries. However, any inserts OR updates do not seem to be working on the "scg2_shard1" connection (everything works on the "default" connection). Any pointers as to what im doing wrong and where should I start looking for to rectify this problem?

Comment: Btw, just to add: I persist objects using JPA.em().persist(entity) (for default) and JPA.em("scg2_shard1").persist(entity) (for the shard)

Comment: Do you get an error or something? And are you sure that the database user has the right privileges?

Comment: The database user has the correct privileges. However, on further investigation, I figured out what the problem is.

Comment: Ok! Could you please answer your own question? Someone else might encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your application.conf

```
jpa.scg2_shard1=shardPersistenceUnit_1
```